# I need a script to delete all the hidden slides in a Google Slides document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I see the function Remove(), but I'm not sure how to make remove identify which slides are hidden

This is what I tried:

```
function deleteHiddenSlides() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();

  for (var i = slides.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (slides[i].isSkipFirstPage() || slides[i].isSkipped()) {
      presentation.removeSlide(i);
    }
  }
}
```

but this is the error I get:
TypeError: slides[i].isSkipFirstPage is not a function

Comment: isSkipFirstPage() is not a method of Class Slide.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it delete slides after the first one skipped using these changes:

```
function deleteHiddenSlides() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  
  for (var i = slides.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (slides[i].isSkipped()) {
      slides.slice(i).forEach(s => s.remove());
    }
  }
}
```

Still far from ideal...

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it :D

```
function deleteHiddenSlides() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  
  for (var i=1; i < slides.length; i++) {
    if (slides[i].isSkipped()) {
      slides[i].remove();
    }
   }
 }
```